# HTML select onChange doesn't fire when value changes

Tags: reactjs

When `this.state.selected` changes, the select box changes its value correctly, but its `onChange` method is not called. This is probably because I need two-way-bindings for that, so I've tried the `valueLink` pattern from [the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html), but it still doesn't get fired:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    React.createElement("select", { valueLink: { value: this.state.selected, requestChange: this.changeHandler } },
       React.createElement("option", { value: 1 }, "1"),
       React.createElement("option", { value: 2 }, "2")
    )
  )
}
```

See the whole fiddle: http://jsbin.com/tisahiliqi/1/edit?html,output

How can I get `requestChange` executed **without** firing an event manually (which is, in my opinion, what two-way-bindings should do for me)?

Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is a little mixed up with React's `LinkedStateMixin`. If you want to fire your own event handler you can use this:
http://jsbin.com/fuwowifoqe/1/

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { selected: 1 }
  },

   componentDidMount: function() {
    // Imagine some AJAX that takes 1s
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      this.setState({ selected: 2 });
    }.bind(this), 1000);
  },

  changeHandler: function(e) {
    // ... Doesn't fire...
    alert("Something changed!");
    this.setState({selected : e.target.value })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement("select", { value: this.state.selected, onChange: this.changeHandler },
         React.createElement("option", { value: 1 }, "1"),
         React.createElement("option", { value: 2 }, "2")
      )
    )
  }
});

React.render(React.createElement(MySelect, null, "Hi"), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Note that the handler is not fired when you change value with `setState`, but when value is changed via user interaction.

---

**UPDATE**

Then you can observe changes to `this.state` or `this.state.selected` using one of the life cycle methods such as `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`:

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/lipovucapi/1/

```
componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState){  
    if(this.state.selected != prevState.selected)
        alert("selected changed!");
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Your last sentence is exactly the point. The handler should not only be fired when the user did something, but also when the app "did" something (e.g. my ajax example above). My app shouldn't care if changes are coming from a user or not. Imagine an observer.